# Conversão de dados string para Json em consulta á collections no mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp

Quando eu faço uma consulta em uma collection no mongodb, a mesma me retorna um campo do tipo string.

```
[{"id":"1325","nome":produto1,"estoque":"10"}]
```

Mas eu preciso fazer com que esse campo seja um Json.

É possível fazer esse tratamento na query usando o Find()?

```
Collection.Find(_=>true).Sort(Builders<Model>.Sort.Descending("_Id")).FirstOrDefault();


class Model
{
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId _Id { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Olhando o código, não está claro o que você está tentando fazer, qual é o problema e onde você está encontrando dificuldade, apresente um [MCVE]

Comment: Só quero pegar uma string e transformar em json. Mas queria saber se e possível fazer essa conversão diretamente na query do mongo.

Comment: Se o objeto for compatível sim, seria melhor você postar a string do json que está recebendo e a estrutura do objeto para deseralização, em nada isso tem a ver com o mongo.Veja que a sua string possui atributos diferentes da model

Comment: [{"id":"1325","nome":produto1,"estoque":"10"}] A string e gravada assim. Ela é montada no código e gravada como string no banco.

Comment: Aonde? no campo mensagem? Não seria melhor a collection do mongo ter as mesmas propriedades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagino que o que você tenha explicado é que essa string é retornada dentro de um campo do objeto consultado. Dito isto, preparei esse pequeno exemplo para você experimentar.

Questão semelhante [#470437](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997839/mongodb-how-to-query-over-a-json-string)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<Model> entities = new List<Model>
        {
            new Model { Mensagem = "[{\"id\":\"1325\",\"nome\":\"produto1\",\"estoque\":\"10\"}]" }
        };

        var productJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(entities.FirstOrDefault().Mensagem).FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(productJson);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("estoque")]
    public int Estoque { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(" ", this.GetType()
                            .GetProperties()
                            .Select(prop => prop.GetValue(this)));
    }
}

class Model
{
    
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _Id { get; set; }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Seria isso sim. Mas para min continua quebrando.

Comment: Imagino que o erro esteja na consulta feita ao Mongodb. Qual o erro que você teve?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: S. Path '', line 1, position 10.'

Comment: A sua string salva está com a formatação errada (o produto sem aspas). Perceba que no meu exemplo eu a corrigi.

Eis a string com formatação correta: [{"id":"1325","nome":"produto1","estoque":"10"}]

Dica: Você pode usar uns validadores de json online. Nesse caso é simples, mas vemos muitos cenários mais complexos.

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#